# F# Winforms Charting Asynchronous Updating

Tags: multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, f#, f#-charting

I'm trying to create a chart in winforms that databinds to a list in memory, and gets updated dynamically as the list changes. Here is my code:

```
open System
open System.Linq
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

let link = new LinkedList<double>()
let rnd = new System.Random()
for i in 1 .. 10 do link.AddFirst(rnd.NextDouble()) |> ignore
let series = new Series()
let chart = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart(Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Palette = ChartColorPalette.Pastel)

series.Points.DataBindY(link)

let form = new Form(Visible = true, Width = 700, Height = 500)
form.Controls.Add(chart)

let formloop = async {
    while not chart.IsDisposed do
        link.AddFirst((new System.Random()).NextDouble()) |> ignore
        link.RemoveLast()
}
do
    Async.StartImmediate(formloop)
    Application.Run(form)

Console.WriteLine("Done")
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

The async seems to work, but the chart never shows anything. It just shows a blank window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`LinkedList<T>` has no way to signal that it's been updated, so `Chart` has no way of knowing when to redraw itself.

In order for databinding to update the view, the source list must implement [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and raise appropriate event when the contents change.

Separately, I must point out that it's dangerous to directly access UI properties/methods from non-UI threads (such as `chart.IsDisposed` in your code). In WinForms, this limitation is rarely actually enforced, so sometimes this might seem to work fine, only to crash later on a customer's machine with no way to attach a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add the series to the `SeriesCollection` of the chart.

  ```
  chart.Series.Add series
  ```
- You need to construct a chart area and add it to the `ChartAreaCollection` of the chart.

  ```
  let area = new ChartArea()
  chart.ChartAreas.Add area
  ```
- You need to make sure that the data binding method is called after the chart and form are set up.

  ```
  ...
  form.Controls.Add chart
  series.Points.DataBindY link
  ```
- And now there's no way to communicate changes of your bound collection to the `DataPointCollection` of the series, as mentioned in [Fyodor Soikin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359217/f-winforms-charting-asynchronous-updating#29359969). I'm not quite sure that `IBindingList` is an appropriate response;
  while it's possible to hook into the `ListChanged` event, we could as well manipulate the series' `DataPointCollection` directly.

  ```
  let formloop = async{
      while not chart.IsDisposed do
          series.Points.RemoveAt 0
          series.Points.AddY(rnd.NextDouble()) |> ignore
          do! Async.Sleep 100 }
  ```
- Finally I'd like to point out this [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472339/is-it-possible-to-use-or-extend-the-fsharpchart-library-to-create-a-line-chart-o#26493898) by John Atwood which adresses both points raised by Fyodor; the data binding issue (by not using it) and the UI-thread safety issue.